# Differences between gnome-terminal and pantheon-terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal

What are the differences between `gnome-terminal` and `pantheon-terminal` and what are the advantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

When comparing Gnome Terminal vs
Pantheon Terminal, the Slant community recommends Pantheon Terminal for most people.

In the question “What are the best Linux terminal emulators?” Pantheon Terminal is ranked 5th while Gnome Terminal is ranked 6th.
The most important reason people chose Pantheon Terminal is:

When a process has ended, Pantheon Terminal sends a notification bubble to the desktop notification server and indicates which tab generated the notification.

Source: https://www.slant.co/versus/2442/2463/~gnome-terminal_vs_pantheon-terminal